# Conversion of Bitmaps from Memory form into file form

Tags: c++, bitmap, portable-executable

What i am trying to accomplish is converting a memory loaded bitmap into a file(.bmp).

I should mention that the bpp:24 and type:RGB.

I am comparing my results with a software called Res hacker which can extract resources from loaded modules as bitmaps

Res hacker result :
           [image: Res hacker result]

Mines : 
       [image: Mines]

There seems to be no problem with the headers (BITMAPINFOHEADER + BITMAPFILEHEADER) , they are similar in both files.

The problem is in the pixel bits , i can't figure about how to convert them from the memory to the file.

```
int PeBmLoader::Get_Bit_Map_File(char *& file,BITMAPFILEHEADER 
*bitmap_file_header,BITMAPINFOHEADER * bitmap_info_header){

int data_size = bitmap_info_header->biSizeImage;
int total_size = data_size + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

unsigned char temp;
file = new char[total_size];
char * data = new char[data_size];

memcpy(file,(char*)bitmap_file_header,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
memcpy(file+sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),   (char*)bitmap_info_header,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
memcpy(data,
       (char*)(bitmap_info_header+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)),
       data_size);

std::cout << bitmap_info_header->biCompression << std::endl;

   memcpy(file+sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),data,data_size);


delete data;

return total_size;}
```

here is the code , as you can see i didn't do anything except copying the pixel bits(data) in a raw form.

Comment: What format are you using for the file, JPEG?  PNG?  TIFF?  GIF? BMP?

Comment: to .bmp format.

Comment: There's a palette immediately following the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, which you aren't dumping to disk. See [Bitmap Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183391.aspx) for details. And look into the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) in case you want to take advantage of a professional bitmap codec.